# kubernetes values files duplicate the value or create reference/sym

Tags: kubernetes, yaml

is it possible in Kubernetes values to refer to value in the same file? I'm doing a for loop and most env vars are fine but this one depends on some other val and need to duplicate/refer to it somehow inside values;

```
image:
  repository: nginx
  tag: stable

someCustomVal:
- name: x
  value: xx
- name: y
  value: yy
- name: z
  value: {{ .Values.image.tag }}
```

btw above config doesn't work but looking for equivalent; I could just do the z value outside of for loop in the deployment but that wouldn't look nice so looking for alternative of referecnce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't Kubernetes-specific, you can do this with [YAML anchors](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2785977):

```
$ cat example.yaml
image:
  repository: nginx
  tag: &imagetag stable

someCustomVal:
- name: x
  value: xx
- name: y
  value: yy
- name: z
  value: *imagetag

$ ruby -ryaml -rpp -e'pp YAML.load_file("example.yaml")'
{"image"=>{"repository"=>"nginx", "tag"=>"stable"},
 "someCustomVal"=>
  [{"name"=>"x", "value"=>"xx"},
   {"name"=>"y", "value"=>"yy"},
   {"name"=>"z", "value"=>"stable"}]}
```